# how to handle different scenarios in posting different data in post action asp.net mvc5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a long form that posts data to 2 or 3 or 4 tables, depends on what checkboxes are selected in view.

My first question: I get an error 'not all code paths return a value'
I realize that I receive this error when there's an unhandled case, but I can't catch this case. Can you please help?

My second question: Can I wrap 
var s_request = new S_REQUEST { //map model properties with vm properties };
in a function to call it multiple times?

Is there any comments on how organized the code is?

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Initiate(SViewModel vm){
             string selectedWorkStepAction = Request["initiationSteps"].ToString();

        switch (selectedWorkStepAction)
        {
            case "0":
                //throw error "Please select an work step action before submission!"
                //stop processing. get out of action
                //don't submit form
                return View(vm);
            case "1":
                if (vm.Coordinates == true)
                {
                    if (vm.ShareWithContractors == false)
                    {
                        using (var context = new SatelliteServicesDBContext())
                        {
                            context.Database.Log = Console.Write;
                            using (DbContextTransaction transaction = context.Database.BeginTransaction())
                            {
                                try
                                {
                                    if (ModelState.IsValid)
                                    {

                                        var s_request = new S_REQUEST
                                        {
                                            //map required properties with coordinates properties, keep few properties null, they will be updated later
                                            //will get written again
                                            //version one                                                
                                        };

                                        db.S_REQUEST.Add(s_request);
                                        db.SaveChanges();

                                        var a_form = new A_FORM
                                        {
                                            //map all properties except one keep it null, will be updated later
                                        };
                                        db.A_FORM.Add(a_form);
                                        db.SaveChanges();


                                        var S_Contractor = new S_CONTRACTOR
                                        {
                                            //reads results from ajax function
                                        };
                                        db.S_CONTRACTOR.Add(S_Contractor);
                                        db.SaveChanges();

                                        //call approve method if data is saved successfully

                                        return View("Success");
                                    }
                                    return View(vm);
                                }
                                catch (Exception)
                                {
                                    transaction.Rollback();
                                    ModelState.AddModelError("SaveError", "Unable to save changes."); //TODO make sure it shows in view not YSOD
                                    //return View(vm);
                                }
                                //return View(vm);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        using (var context = new SatelliteServicesDBContext())
                        {
                            context.Database.Log = Console.Write;
                            using (DbContextTransaction transaction = context.Database.BeginTransaction())
                            {
                                try
                                {
                                    if (ModelState.IsValid)
                                    {
                                        var s_request = new S_REQUEST
                                        {
                                            //map required properties with coordinates properties, keep few properties null, they will be updated later 
                                            //version one                                           
                                        };

                                        db.S_REQUEST.Add(s_request);
                                        db.SaveChanges();

                                        var a_form = new A_FORM
                                        {
                                           //map all properties except one keep it null, will be updated later 

                                        };
                                        db.A_FORM.Add(a_form);
                                        db.SaveChanges();
                                        //call approve method if data is saved successfully
                                        return View("Success");
                                    }
                                    return View(vm);
                                }
                                catch (Exception)
                                {
                                    transaction.Rollback();
                                    ModelState.AddModelError("SaveError", "Unable to save changes."); //TODO make sure it shows in view not YSOD
                                                                                                      //return View(vm);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                else //Coordinates checkbox is not checked
                {
                    if (vm.ShareWithContractors == false)
                    {
                        using (var context = new SatelliteServicesDBContext())
                        {
                            context.Database.Log = Console.Write;
                            using (DbContextTransaction transaction = context.Database.BeginTransaction())
                            {
                                try
                                {
                                    if (ModelState.IsValid)
                                    {

                                        var s_request = new S_REQUEST
                                        {
                                            //only required properties
                                            //version two
                                        };

                                        db.S_REQUEST.Add(s_request);
                                        db.SaveChanges();

                                        var a_form = new A_FORM
                                        {
                                            //map all properties except one keep it null, will be updated later 
                                        };
                                        db.A_FORM.Add(a_form);
                                        db.SaveChanges();

                                        var file = new MAP
                                        {
                                            //reads results from ajax function 1
                                            //map all properties
                                        };
                                        db.MAP.Add(file);
                                        db.SaveChanges();

                                        var S_Contractor = new S_CONTRACTOR
                                        {
                                            //reads results from ajax function 2
                                            //map all properties
                                        };
                                        db.S_CONTRACTOR.Add(S_Contractor);
                                        db.SaveChanges();

                                        //call approve method if data is saved successfully
                                        return View("Success");
                                    }
                                    return View(vm);
                                }
                                catch (Exception)
                                {
                                    transaction.Rollback();
                                    ModelState.AddModelError("SaveError", "Unable to save changes."); //TODO make sure it shows in view not YSOD
                                                                                                      //return View(vm);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        using (var context = new SatelliteServicesDBContext())
                        {
                            context.Database.Log = Console.Write;
                            using (DbContextTransaction transaction = context.Database.BeginTransaction())
                            {
                                try
                                {
                                    if (ModelState.IsValid)
                                    {
                                        var s_request = new S_REQUEST
                                        {
                                           //only required properties
                                            //version two
                                        };

                                        db.S_REQUEST.Add(s_request);
                                        db.SaveChanges();

                                        var a_form = new A_FORM
                                        {
                                            //map all properties except one keep it null, will be updated later 

                                        };
                                        db.A_FORM.Add(a_form);
                                        db.SaveChanges();

                                        var file = new MAP
                                        {
                                            //reads results from ajax function
                                        };
                                        db.MAP.Add(file);
                                        db.SaveChanges();

                                        //call approve method if data is saved successfully
                                        return View("Success");
                                    }
                                    return View(vm);
                                }
                                catch (Exception)
                                {
                                    transaction.Rollback();
                                    ModelState.AddModelError("SaveError", "Unable to save changes."); //TODO make sure it shows in view not YSOD
                                                                                                      //return View(vm);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                break;

            case "2":
                try
                {
                    if (ModelState.IsValid)
                    {

                        var s_request = new S_REQUEST
                        {
                            //only required properties
                            //version two
                        };

                        db.S_REQUEST.Add(s_request);
                        db.SaveChanges();

                        //delegate method should be called if data is saved successfully

                        return View("Success");
                    }
                    return View(vm);
                }
                catch
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("SaveError", "Unable to save changes."); 
                    //TODO make sure it shows in view not YSOD
                    //Console.Write("check error:    " + ex);
                    //return View(vm); //should be inside catch, right?
                }
                break;
            case "3":
                //don't save to any table
                //call cancel method
                return RedirectToAction("Services", "Home");
        }
    }
```

Comment: return RedirectToAction("Services", "Home"); statement should be just before the closing of Initiate method. that solve your return path error

Comment: } return RedirectToAction("Services", "Home");

    }